# Solving an equation takes too long

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation `func[a, b, c, d, e] == 0` where

```
func[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] = -c + 1.77109 Sqrt[c] (1/Sqrt[c] + 1/Sqrt[d])^(1/3) - 1.1501 a c 
     (1/Sqrt[c] + 1/Sqrt[d])^(2/3) - 2 Sqrt[c] Sqrt[d] + 1.77109 (1/Sqrt[c] + 1/Sqrt[d])^
          (1/3) Sqrt[d] - 2.3 a Sqrt[c] (1/Sqrt[c] + 1/Sqrt[d])^(2/3) Sqrt[d] - d - 
     1.1501 a (1/Sqrt[c] + 1/Sqrt[d])^(2/3) d + c e + (d e)/(-1 + e) + Sqrt[2] b c e^2 - 
     (Sqrt[2] b d e^2)/(-1 + e)^2;
```

using `Solve` as follows:

```
Solve[func[a, b, c, d, e] == 0 && 10000 > c > 1 && 1000 > e > 1 && 1000 > d > 1  &&
     -3 < a < 3 && -3 < b < 3, c, Reals]
```

but it is taking too long and still running (more than 2 days).

Do I miss something or is it to be expected?

Comment: So… you want to express `c` in terms of the other variables?

Comment: Only numericall.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want c in terms of other variables.

Answer (score 4):

While it seems obvious that no good can come of trying to analytically solve this mess, lets do a variable substitution:

```
 Collect[Simplify[
     Numerator@
      Together[
          FullSimplify[ func[a, b, (Sqrt[d]/(-1 + Sqrt[d] z))^2 , d, e],
            Assumptions -> {z > 1/Sqrt[d], d > 0}] /. z -> z3^3], 
              Assumptions -> z3 > 0], z3]
```

I won't even post the result, but what you have is an 8th order polynomial.
So, in principle if you let `Solve` go at it for eons it will generate an enormous collection of `Root` expressions, which are effectively useless until you substitute numeric values.  All that is to say forget about analytic solutions and use `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an example for a root you can put in some numbers and use:

```
 FindRoot[func[1, 1, c, 2, 2], {c, 3}]
```

> {c -> 3.3652}

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to find a general solution _c=g(a,b,d,e)_